# what is wkernel32.pdb

Tags: windbg

When I am trying to reload the symbol for kernel32.dll, the windbg always complain below:

```
DBGHELP: d:\symbols\wkernel32.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: d:\symbols\dll\wkernel32.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: d:\symbols\symbols\dll\wkernel32.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: C:\Windows\syswow64\wkernel32.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: wkernel32.pdb - file not found
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll -
```

What is wkernel32.dll and how can I get the symbol information for that file?

I have installed the right package of the windows symbol, I have verified the version string, it's exactly match.

Thanks.
Bin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure but it could be that wkernel32.pdb is specified as the symbol database file for your kernel32.dll. You could check by looking at the strings inside kernel32.dll using process explorer.

Also, it looks like wkernel32.dll is related to WoW (Windows over Windows). Do you have a 64 bit machine?

Comment: Yes, I am using 64bit machine. But the problem is the symbol file is not contained in the windows symbol package.

Answer (score 1):

If your debugger session has internet access, try using the [MS symbol server](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/debugstart.mspx) by running this: `.symfix; .reload` in windbg.

Answer (score 0):

Also you use the command !sym noisy

This will output the locations that symbols are being looked for.